# Restriction of polynomials of order $m$ to $(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification

Let $\{p_k \}_k$ denote a sequence of polynomials of order $m$ and let $\{t_1, \ldots, t_n\}$ denote $n$ distinct points in $[0,1]$ with $n \geq m$. I know that

$$ \lim_k p_k(t_i) \quad \text{exists}, \quad i = 1, \ldots, n $$

Can I conclude that the limit is a polynomial? It would seem to me that this is the case since the vector space of polynomials of order $m$ is finite-dimensional and hence closed.  If this is true, could someone point me to a relevant formal result?

Comment: Are you assuming $m=n$?

Comment: I am assuming $n>m$ only.

Comment: Then consider $m=2$, $n=1$ and $t_1=0$. How about the sequence $p_k(x)=k x^2$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven That's a nice counter-example for $m>n$. What about $n>m$ though?

Comment: My guess is that it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n < m+1$ then the claim is not true: One can construct a non-zero polynomial $p$ of degree $m$ that is zero at all points $t_i$. Then set $p_k:=k\cdot p$.

Let me suppose $m+1=n$.

Let me denote the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $m$ by $V$ supplied with some norm. Then $dim(V)=m+1$.

The evaluation functionals $\phi_i(p):=p(t_i)$ are linearly independent (use Lagrange polynomials). Since  there are $m+1$ such functionals, and the dimension of the dual space $V^*$ of $V$ is equal to the dimension of $V$, these functionals form a basis of $V^*$.

Using Lagrange polynomials again, there is exactly one polynomial $p$ of degree at most $m$ such that $\phi_i(p) = \lim_k \phi_i(p_k)$ for all $i$.

Let now $\phi\in V^*$ be given. Then $\phi$ is a finite linear combination of these $(\phi_i)$, and it follows $\phi(p_k) \to \phi(p)$.
This implies weak convergence of $(p_k)$ to  $p$.
Since the underlying vector space is finite-dimensional, we have strong convergence of $p_k$ to $p$.

---

Another possible proof is the following one: The map $p\mapsto \sum_i |\phi_i(p)|$ is a norm on $V$ (this needs $m+1\le n$). Then $(p_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in this norm.
But $V$ is finite-dimensional, hence complete, and $p_k$ is converging.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I'll examine your argument in detail.

Comment: I understand your argument up until the very last paragraph. Can you elaborate a bit about the weak convergence to the polynomial $p$? Afterwards, I know that in finite-dimensional spaces weak and strong convergence are identical.

Comment: See edit. There are really many options here. One could also show that $p\mapsto \sum_i |\phi_i(p)|$ is a norm on $V$. Then the sequence $(p_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence in this norm...

Comment: I think you also use the fact that for the lagrange polynomial basis $\psi_i$ you have $\phi_i(\psi_j) = \delta_{ij}$, right? To assert the convergence to $p$, I mean.

Comment: Yes.................

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to.